# How many RAM can i add and who are the manufacturer?

Tags: memory

I have two RAM chips in my Mac. How can i get to know, how many of them can i upgrade? I mean, it could happen, that one (or even two) of them are soldered on…?

And, how is it possible to get out who is the manufacturer of RAM? - three are only cryptical codes, like `0xAD00000000000000`… I wouldn't like to buy RAM from manufacturer, who doesn't match with the RAM already installed.

It goes about the following hardware:

```
MacBook Pro
15 Zoll, 2,4 2,2 GHz
Prozessor  2,2 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
NVIDIA GeForce 8600M GT 128 MB
Serial Number: W874214LX91

RAM:

BANK 0/DIMM0:
Size:   2 GB
Typ:    DDR2 SDRAM
Tact Frequency: 667 MHz
Status: OK
Manufacturer:   0xAD00000000000000
Part Number:    0x48594D503132355336344350382D59352020
Serial Number:  0x00006170

BANK 1/DIMM1:
Size:   1 GB
Typ:    DDR2 SDRAM
Tact Frequency: 667 MHz
Status: OK
Manufacturer:   0x7F7F7F7F7F7FC100
Part Number:    0x4232594A55533733464E3120202020202020
Serial Number:  0x00000058
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your serial number I was able to determine that you're running a **Macbook Pro 15" from Late 2007**. These models generally came standard with 2GB of RAM. Both the link that @William T Froggard provided (http://www.appleserialnumberinfo.com) and an application called Mactracker state that the maximum amount of RAM Apple *recommends* for this model is **4GB**. People have reported having success with up to 6GB, *but functionality is not guaranteed by Apple*. This would mean that the optimum setup for your Mac would be to have **two 2GB modules of RAM installed**, one in each slot. (As @William T Froggard also mentioned, Macs function better with RAM that is installed in identical pairs.)

Once again the brand name/manufacturer doesn't matter too much (although *Crucial* and *Kingston* are very well known, established names). The most important part is that the RAM is **200-pin PC2-5300 (667MHz) DDR2 SO-DIMM.**

Macbook Pro Tech Specs, as per Mactracker.app:
[image: Macbook Pro Tech Specs, as per Mactracker.app]

Comment: could you please point me to any review about success with 6GB RAM?

Comment: http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/6gb-in-macbook-pro-yes-it-works-8gb-well.573906/

Answer (score 3):

Apple did not solder RAM in those days, so you should be good to go. As far as the manufacturer is concerned, it really doesn't matter. As long as the modules are from a good (and ideally the same) manufacturer (crucial has been good in my experience), match the required specs which you can find at sites such as http://www.appleserialnumberinfo.com by entering your serial number, you'll be good to go.

I would also advise that you use the same sizes of memory modules in both banks. You currently have an imbalance, which can negatively impact performance.